Mapping pixels of one GeoTIFF to another
I need to map the pixels of one GeoTIFF onto another.  Both are of the moon.
My thought process was to:

Convert a pixel on the source tif into the source model-space using the source tif's ModelTiePoint and PixelScale
Use proj to convert source model-space coordinate to target model-space coordinate
Using the target tif's ModelTiePoint and PixelScale, convert the target model-space coordinate into a pixel coordinate on the target tif.

The C++ code (using libgeotiff and proj) looks like this:
// Initialize:
PJ_CONTEXT* ctx = proj_context_create();
PJ* psPJ = proj_create_crs_to_crs(ctx, source.projStr.c_str(), target.projStr.c_str(), NULL);

// Normally, this would be in a for-loop over all pixels:
// Convert from original pixel space to target space:
PJ_COORD coord;
coord.xyzt.x = (pixel_x_source * source.pixelScale[0]) + source.modelTiePoint[0];
coord.xyzt.y = (pixel_y_source * (-1 * source.pixelScale[1])) + source.modelTiePoint[1];
coord.xyzt.z = 0;
coord.xyzt.t = 0;

// Perform re-projection:
PJ_COORD coordout = proj_trans(psPJ, PJ_FWD, coord);

// Convert from target space to target model-space:
double modelX = coordout.xyzt.x - target.modelTiePoint[0];
double modelY = coordout.xyzt.y - target.modelTiePoint[1];
     
// Convert from taget model-space to target pixel-space:
double pixel_x_targ = modelX / target.pixelScale[0];
double pixel_y_targ = modelY / (-1 * target.pixelScale[1]);

// Do stuff with the newly projected pixel coordinates...

// Clean-up:
proj_destroy(psPJ);
proj_context_destroy(ctx);

For two image pairs with this data, it works as expected:
source.pixelScale = {7580.8400000000001, 7580.8400000000001};
source.modelTiePoint = {-5458204.7999999998, 2729102.3999999999};
source.projStr = "+proj=eqc +lat_0=0.000000000 +lon_0=180.000000000 +lat_ts=0.000000000 +x_0=0.000 +y_0=0.000 +a=1737400.000 +b=1737400.000 +units=m ";

target.pixelScale = {99.747863237334002, 99.747863237334002};
target.modelTiePoint = {0, 1819401.0254490720};
target.projStr = "+proj=eqc +lat_0=0.000000000 +lon_0=0.000000000 +lat_ts=0.000000000 +x_0=0.000 +y_0=0.000 +a=1737400.000 +b=1737400.000 +units=m ";

However, for image pairs with the following data, it does not work as expected:
source.pixelScale = {7580.8400000000001, 7580.8400000000001};
source.modelTiePoint = {-5458204.7999999998, 2729102.3999999999};
source.projStr = "+proj=eqc +lat_0=0.000000000 +lon_0=180.000000000 +lat_ts=0.000000000 +x_0=0.000 +y_0=0.000 +a=1737400.000 +b=1737400.000 +units=m ";

target.pixelScale = {99.747863237334002, 99.747863237334002};
target.modelTiePoint = {5458203.0763470158, 1819401.0254490720};
target.projStr = "+proj=eqc +lat_0=0.000000000 +lon_0=0.000000000 +lat_ts=0.000000000 +x_0=0.000 +y_0=0.000 +a=1737400.000 +b=1737400.000 +units=m ";

Because in both cases the "source tif" is a global map that covers the entire moon, there should be some pixels that overlap with the "target tif".  However, the algorithm, I've written above produces a set of output pixels that are ALWAYS outside of the target tif's resolution (they are always negative).
What I believe is going on is that the "source tif" has lon_0=+180, and as-such a negative modelTiePoint[0].  It's model-space x coordinates range from -5458204.7999999998 to 5458204.7999999998.  In contrast, the "target tif" has lon_0=0.0, with it's model-space x coordinates spanning from 5458203.0763470158 to 8187304.615...
The model-space of the "source tif" corresponds to a longitude range of -180 to +180, while both of the "target tifs" are setup to have a longitude range from 0 to 360.  Therefore it would make sense that the first one works (as it's longitude falls within 0 to 180), but the second to fail (as its longitude is >180 and thus outside the -180 to 180 bounds).
My confusion is that I would have assumed proj would appropriately handle projecting from lon_0=+180 to lon_0=0 and vice-versa making this a non-issue but clearly I was wrong.  What is the correct way to handle this in a generalized way?

Edit 0:
Using the code above, I've walked through a set of x-coordinates from the source image and projected them onto 4 target images (LDEM_4 onto 4 albedo tiles, see below edits for details).  This graph may be slightly confusing, but I believe highlights the problem.
The x-axis of the graph is the pixel-column of the source image.  The y-axis is the model-space coordinate it is mapped to.  The solid black line is the model-space of the source tif (it is a straight line ranging from -5e6 to 5e6, as it goes from a longitude of 0 to 360).  The colored lines are the model-space coordinate of the point projected onto one of the target tifs (Albedos 0-4, denoted as A0, A1, A2, A3 respectively).

The first two Albedo maps are projected correctly, which makes sense with this plot since for each the model-space coordinates LDEM_4 is mapped to range from 0 to ~2e6.  However the model-space coordinates wrap at a longitude of 180, and thus the remaining model-space coordinates for A2 and A3 have negative model-space coordinates, which lead to negative pixel values and thus are not detected as being mapped onto.
That wrapping is therefore incorrect, but I am not sure why it is happening.  It makes sense that " +over" would solve this, though that approach is clearly not generally correct.  The comment referring to changing the lon_0 would appear to be correct, but it is not obvious to me how to make such a change automatically based just on the meta-data of the file.

Edit 1 - Demonstrations:
The data-sets in question come from:

Albedos: https://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/view_rdr/WAC_EMP (select the 643NM wavelength (304d) from the dropdown to see all 10 tiles).  Specifically the PDS IMG files for each.
Heights:  https://imbrium.mit.edu/BROWSE/LOLA_GDR/CYLINDRICAL/ELEVATION/ Specifically the LDEM_4 0.25 deg/pixel resolution (the PDS IMG/LBL pair)

I convert these to geotiffs using (2 shown for example):
gdal_translate -of GTiff LDEM_4.LBL LDEM_4.tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff WAC_EMP_643NM_P900N0000_304P.IMG WAC_EMP_643NM_P900N0000_304P.tif

When reading, I get the projStr for each tif loaded using the following code:
// ...
// Open file:
TIFF* tif = XTIFFOpen(filepath.c_str(), "r");
GTIF* gtif = GTIFNew(tif);

// Extract proj4 string:
GTIFDefn* psDefn = GTIFAllocDefn();
GTIFGetDefn(gtif, psDefn);
char* pszProjection = GTIFGetProj4Defn(psDefn);
config.projStr = std::string(pszProjection);
CPLFree(pszProjection);
// ...

By just running the code I have presented above and attempting to project the pixels of all 10 albedo tiles onto the pixels of LDEM_4, this is what I get (white pixels correspond to pixels that are unassigned due to not having anything projected onto them:

I can achieve what I am expecting to see by appending " +over" to the end of each projStr.  This breaks other uses of my code so this is not a solution itself, but it produces the result I am expecting to see.  This is all 10 albedo maps (2 stereographic polar tiles, and 8 cylindrical map tiles) mapped onto the pixels of LDEM_4:

(^ the white patches at the poles are due to no albedo data being present, they correspond to permanently shadowed regions at the poles, which is irrelevant to the problem here)

Edit 2 - More confusion:
The LDEM_4 tif comes with the following annotated png (presumably showing how it is projected):

When I look at the actual TIF itself, I find the following:

part of the output from gdalinfo LDEM_4:
Upper Left  (-5458204.800, 2729102.400) (  0d 0' 0.20"W, 90d 0' 0.10"N)
Lower Left  (-5458204.800,-2729102.400) (  0d 0' 0.20"W, 90d 0' 0.10"S)
Upper Right ( 5458204.800, 2729102.400) (  0d 0' 0.20"E, 90d 0' 0.10"N)
Lower Right ( 5458204.800,-2729102.400) (  0d 0' 0.20"E, 90d 0' 0.10"S)

This would imply that the left edge of the image is at 0d longitude, which appears to match with what is shown in the annotated image.  While the annotated image goes from -180 to +180, the actual TIF goes from 0 to 360 in terms of pixels, which makes sense.  And further explains why the TIF's lon_0=180 according to the comment.  My confusion then is why the model-space coordinates of the left-edge at -5458204.800 if they correspond to the 0d longitude?
Because when I look at an albedo tile that starts at 0d longitude:

part of the output from gdalinfo LDEM_4:
Upper Left  (       0.000, 1819401.025) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000001) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( 2729101.538, 1819401.025) ( 90d 0' 0.00"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 2729101.538,       0.000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"N)

it starts at 0d longitude as well, but it's model space coordinates at the left edge are 0.  I suppose this also makes sense as to why the TIF's lon_0=0, however it leaves me confused as to what the actual solution is for mapping one of these onto the other.

If the left edge of the eqc-projected source tiff is -5 million and corresponds to -180, set lon_0 to 0. If you want the left edge to instead correspond to 0 longitude, set the target lon_0 to +180. I think you need to think about where various longitude values are in the projected space. With 0 to 360 unprojected raster, set the lon_0 of the projcrs to the longitude you want to be in the center.

My issue is I have rasters that are defined differently, some with lon_0=0 and some with lon_0=180.  The GeoTIFF itself specifies the lon_0.  It isn't clear to me how to automatically determine how to change these values to get my automated use-case to work correctly.  If I just set the lon_0 of source tif with a left edge at -5million, it still does not work (instead mapping the albedos to the wrong part of the image)  I've updated my post to include these examples
